# Selecting the "li" element after the a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically,

I have a navigation that looks something like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
```

What I need to do is add a class to the `<li>` tag that is directly before it. The link would therefore look like so:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
```

I have tried to use the following:

```
 $(document).find("a:contains('Testing')").each(function(){
    var element=$(this);

  });
```

I therefore assume that `element` refers to the `a` tag, but, even when I have tried to use `.prev()` it still does not select the right tag.

What can I use to select the `<li>` element?

Comment: FYI, `$(document).find("a:contains('Testing')")` should just be `$("a:contains('Testing')")`

Comment: What you actually want to achieve? If you want to add `active` class to the `li` whose anchor tag is clicked then you can either use `.parent()` or by selecting all `li` directly and add class to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

li element is parent of anchor tag. You need to use `.parent()` or `.closest()` instead of using `.prev()`:

```
$("a:contains('Testing')").parent().addClass('active');
```

or

```
$("a:contains('Testing')").closest('li').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) jquery selector:

```
$("li:has(a:contains('Testing'))")
```

Or [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method:

```
$('li').has("a:contains('Testing')")
```